# What is the validity of RequestToken obtained in OAuth?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth

I have searched a lot but still haven't found out. What is the validity of **`RequestToken`** obtained during **`OAuth`** ? or How can I keep the **`RequestToken`** from expiring ?

Answer (score 1):

The [OAuth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2) does not define an expiration time for request tokens, it just recommends that it have a limited lifetime. If the implementation sets an expiration time, you can't keep it from expiring, you'll have to request a new token.

Comment: But there is a difference between `RequestToken` and `AccessToken`